# OfflineIMAP and Mutt with Gmail's All Mail folder

Tags: gmail, imap, mutt

**OfflimeIMAP**

I am trying to sync my Gmail - All Mail folder with idlefolders through offlineimap. My .offlineimaprc config has this -

```
idlefolders = ['INBOX', '[Gmail].All Mail']
```

My name of my All Mail folder in .mail (where my mailboxes are) looks like

```
drwx------ 5 ry ry    4096 Oct 12 18:13 [Gmail].All Mail
```

I think the name is wrong in idlefolders. I see a lot of people online using [Gmail]/All Mail.

My INBOX folder sync fine but All Mail does not.

**MUTT**

Also trying to set a macro shortcut to All Mail in .muttrc I have -

```
macro index ga  "<change-folder> =[Gmail].All Mail<enter>"
```

This *does not* work, but my macro for INBOX *does* work

```
macro index gi  "<change-folder> =INBOX<enter>"
```

What's wrong? How should I call my All Mail folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is the whitespace in the folder. Possible solutions:

1. **Update:** As winchendonsprings pointed out, there is a way to escape the whitespace in the folder name. Now we can use a macro to change to `All Mail`:

   ```
   bind editor <space> noop
   macro index ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail].All Mail<enter>" "Go to all mail"
   ```
2. You use a name transalation to create mailboxes without a
   [whitespace as described in the
   documentation](http://docs.offlineimap.org/en/latest/nametrans.html).
   For example the translation could look like this:

   ```
   nametrans = lambda x: re.sub('\[|\]|\s', '_', x)
   ```

   You should make sure, as the documentation states, that no folder
   ends up with the same translated name. You can check this by running
   offlineimap with `--info`.
3. Another possible solution could be, to register your mailboxes and
   simply use a macro to toggle between the index and your list of configured
   mailboxes, eg. in your `.muttrc`:

   ```
   mailboxes =[Gmail].All\ Mail =[Gmail].Important =[Gmail].Starred
   macro index <left> ':mailboxes <enter>c?<toggle-mailboxes>
   ```

   That provides the benefit that mutt monitors your local mailbox and
   tells you if you've got new mail. You can even automate this if you want. [Examples can be found here.](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/ConfigTricks)

Comment: It says "The folderfilter operates on the UNTRANSLATED name (before any nametrans fudging takes place)." So what would be the untranslated name for 'All Mail' in Gmail? I believe your solution for nametrans would work, but as a workaround. Unless there is no way to use a folderfilter for 'All Mail.'

Comment: The UNTRANSLATED name should be: ``[Gmail]/All Mail``. At least that's what ``offlineimap --info`` spits out for me, not using a name translation.

Comment: You were right! offlineIMAP sees Gmail All Mail folder as [Gmail]/All Mail . It saves it as [Gmail].All Mail . So Mutt needs this for a macro - bind editor <space> noop
macro index ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail].All Mail<enter>" "Go to all mail" @romanofski

Comment: Ah - well there you have it. The <space> noop "escapes" the whitespace.

Comment: I've tried all the options and having offlineimap configured to strip `[Gmail]` via `nametrans`, still space had been troublemaker for `Sent Mail` and `All Mail` until I added the `<space> noop` fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

for my Mutt 1.5.21, percent encoding works:

```
macro index ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/All%20Mail<enter>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another terrible solution is to just use `<complete>` to avoid typing a literal space:

```
macro index ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/All<complete><enter>"
```